# OpenGL - draw line with points

Tags: java, opengl, line, jogl

The exercise I have is the following:
In display() add a method drawLine. Probably, you will need something like 
drawLine(GL gl, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
now using the equation of a line, plot the individual points that make up the line from x1,y1 to x2,y2 in JOGL 
using (for instance) gl.glPointSize(1.0f); gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);
If you have coloured the points white, and used the following projections

```
gl.glViewport(-250, -150, 250, 150);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
glu.gluOrtho2D(-250.0, 250.0, -150.0, 150.0);
```

then with a value of a line from points (0,0) to (100,100) yours will look 
something like the following picture:

[image]

My code so far for the EventListener where I create my line is the following:

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;


public class ThirdGLEventListener implements GLEventListener {

/**
 * Interface to the GLU library.
 */
private GLU glu;

/**
 * Take care of initialization here.
 */
public void init(GLAutoDrawable gld) {
    GL gl = gld.getGL();
    glu = new GLU();

    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);


    gl.glViewport(-250, -150, 250, 150);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluOrtho2D(-250.0, 250.0, -150.0, 150.0);
}

/**
 * Take care of drawing here.
 */
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {



    GL gl = drawable.getGL();

    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*
     * put your code here
     */

    drawLine(gl, 0, 0, 100, 100);

}

public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width,
        int height) {
}

public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable drawable,
        boolean modeChanged, boolean deviceChanged) {
}

private void drawLine(GL gl, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    gl.glPointSize(1.0f);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);

    // This is where the whole problem lies. 

    gl.glEnd();//end drawing of points

}
```

}

My problem is that I don't quite know how to complete the code inside the method for the line equation. I would appreciate it if you could help me with that bit. I think the rest of it is just right, I just need to find how to implement the line equation inside the drawLine() method.

Comment: This sounds like the worst graphics programming homework ever conceived. You should do some reading up and it will become apparent quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `GL_LINES`:

```
private void drawLine(GL gl, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    gl.glPointSize(1.0f);
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_POINTS);

    int samples = 100;
    float dx = (x2 - x1) / (float)samples;
    float dy = (y2 - y1) / (float)samples;

    for( int i = 0; i < samples; i++ )
    {
        gl.glVertex2f( i * dx, i * dy );
    } 

    gl.glEnd();//end drawing of points
}
```

Adjust `samples` to taste.

Comment: Basically, doing the same thing I did :) and plus you should read his comments more carefully! because of which I have edited my responses thrice!

Comment: Using this approach, I realized I have to change the coordinate values every time I use the method according to the samples value. That is, the samples value cannot be larger that my coordinate values. When I use the drawline method in my display() like this:
`drawLine(gl, 0, 0, 250, 250);` , then the samples value cannot be larger that 250. How can I fix this then?

Comment: My Java's pretty rusty, but try casting `samples` to `float` before dividing: `float dx = (x2 - x1) / (float)samples;`

Comment: This stuff is deprecated with OpenGL 3.1

Answer (score 2):

Thats how you do it in OpenGL.

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
   for(float i = 0; i <= 100; ){
      glVertex2f(i,i);
      i+=0.01;
   }
glEnd();
```

Also, a suggestion you want to have your Orthographic projections in GL_PROJECTION matrix and your modelview like the above code in GL_MODELVIEW

Edited play around with your `+=0.01` and you will get the results BETTER WAY

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
   glVertex2i(0,0);
   glVertex2i(100,100);
glEnd();
```

Comment: I understand, however I do believe the GL_POINTS is required. Is there any way to use the points to create such a line starting at x1,y1 and ending at x2,y2?

Comment: Change the i+=0.01 to what you require if you need to do it with `GL_POINTS`. I have updated it accordingly

Comment: hmmm That seems like a great solution to my problem. Excuse me if I'm getting tiring but I'm not too familiar with OpenGL. Since a drawLine() method is required, shouldn't I uses some code that involves the  `GL gl, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2` ?

Comment: if you want to use something like that you only need to use the earlier function the one I removed.